# How can I get clang-format to change only indent width?

Tags: clang-format

I have a large code base that I want to standardise the indent width for.
How can I do this with clang-format without making other changes?

Passing `-style='{IndentWidth: 2}'` to clang-format

makes other changes to the source files as `-dump-config` implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang-format doesn't support that at all. You might get somewhat close to that by setting "ColumnLimit: 0" which will make clang-format accept the existing line breaks to a certain extent.